# Display data on the label

Tags: asp.net

currently I'm using asp.net to create a web service & web application and require to get database data through web service. Now I have done all this part, just want to know how to display the data without the field name appear and display the name,add, etc on on diff label. Thanks. Apologise for not writing a proper question.

Comment: If you don't ask a proper question, how will you expect a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

You question is somewhat open ended and it is difficult to give any specific answer but data binding is going to be your friend in this situation. Here is a [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) that will get you started.